# read a single *.xlsx file in R without the use of filename but utilizing the *.xlsx

Tags: r, readxl, r-xlsx

I download an xlxs file everyday with a long unique name with dates each day. I need R to read the new xlsx file saved in the directory everyday without typing the unique name everyday. My idea is to utilize the *.xlsx but whenever I try it, it always say the path does not exist:

```
excel_df <- read_excel("C:/Home/User/dbd/*.xlsx")
```

the code above does not work

This code says the same:

```
base <- as.character("C:/Home/User/dbd/*.xlsx")

files <- file.info(list.files(path = base, pattern = '*.xlsx',
                              full.names = TRUE, no.. = TRUE))
daily_numebrs<-readxl::read_excel(rownames(files)[order(files$mtime)][nrow(files)])
```

each line of results shows the

```
...path does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

The path shouldn't contain the pattern:

```
path <- "C:/Home/User/dbd"
files <- list.files(path= path, full.names=T, pattern ='\\.xlsx$')
files
lapply(files, function(file) readxl::read_excel(file))
```